# Get non html text value

Tags: .net, vb.net

I get data from db that stores html value, I want only to get the text without html element

```
Me.txtArea1.InnerHtml = _subject +  _body
```

when I do that the value appear like that

```
subject <p>body</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the html from DB.

```
string html = "subject <p>body</p>";
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
string textOnly = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText; // "subject body"
```

Answer (score 1):

Import RegEx on top:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Then, use like this:

```
Me.txtArea1.InnerHtml = _subject +  Regex.Replace(_body, "<.*?>", "")
```